# Running a simple Qt program

Tags: qt, compiler-errors

I have done the following to run a simple `Qt` program:

- Created a `hello` folder
- Created a `hello.cpp` program as follows:

> ```
>    #include <QApplication>
>     #include <QLabel>
>
>     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
>     {
>     QApplication app(argc, argv);
>     QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello...");
>     label->show();
>     return app.exec();
>     }
> ```

- Ran `qmake -project`
- Ran `qmake hello.pro` ---> Here I get `Makefile`
- Ran 'make', and here, I get something like this and which seems to continue proceeding unless I stop it:

> c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe
>   c:\Users\Ola\Desktop\hello\hell
>       o.pro -o Makefile.hello
>       make -f Makefile.hello
>       make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/hello'
>       c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe c:\Users\Ola\Desktop\hello\hell
>       o.pro -o Makefile.hello.hello
>       make -f Makefile.hello.hello
>       make[2]: Entering directory`/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/hello'
>       c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe c:\Users\Ola\Desktop\hello\hell
>       o.pro -o Makefile.hello.hello.hello
>       make -f Makefile.hello.hello.hello
>       make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/hello'
>       c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe c:\Users\Ola\Desktop\hello\hell
>       o.pro -o Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make -f Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make[4]: Entering directory`/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/hello'
>       c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe c:\Users\Ola\Desktop\hello\hell
>       o.pro -o Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make -f Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make[5]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/hello'
>       c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe c:\Users\Ola\Desktop\hello\hell
>       o.pro -o Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make -f Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make[6]: Entering directory`/c/Users/Ola/Desktop/hello'
>       c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\qmake.exe c:\Users\Ola\Desktop\hello\hell
>       o.pro -o Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make -f Makefile.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello.hello
>       make[6]: *** [sub-hello-pro-make_default] Interrupt
>       make[5]: *** [sub-hello-pro-make_default] Interrupt
>       make[4]: *** [sub-hello-pro-make_default] Interrupt
>       make[3]: *** [sub-hello-pro-make_default] Interrupt
>       make[2]: *** [sub-hello-pro-make_default] Interrupt
>       make[1]: *** [sub-hello-pro-make_default] Interrupt
>       make: *** [sub-hello-pro-make_default] Interrupt

How can I run the program?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, can you show your .pro file?

Comment: @ Luca Carlon. It didn't get generated! I don't know why?!

Comment: Luca was asking about hello.pro. You don't have to use qmake hello.pro, it's enough to use qmake without parameters as it will find .pro file in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Qt Command Prompt installed with Qt installation package. Then, instead of using `make`, use `mingw32-make`.

It works for me.